# Replacing values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

i want to replace `x[1]` with `x[2]` if `x[2] == 2` for each list of list, but am getting a syntax error.

```
My_dict = {
    'Dataset 1': {'Subset' : [[1,4,2],[4,5,5]], 'key' : ['rand1', 'rand2']},
    'Dataset 2': {'Subset' : [[4,3,4],[3,4,2]], 'key' : ['rand4', 'rand3']}
    }

for key in My_dict:
   My_dict[key]['Subset'] = [x[1] = x[2] for x if x[2] == 2]
   print My_dict[key]['Subset']
```

Desired Output:

```
[[1,2,2],[4,5,5]]
[[4,3,4],[3,2,2]]
```

Comment: Should be `x[1] == x[2]`

Comment: == is for test of equivalency. I am assigning `x[1]` equal to `x[2]`

Comment: you can't in a list comprehension... :p (unless you get creative, but assignments like that are not what list comprehensions are for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list comprehension starts with an **expression**, and assignment (as you're trying to do) in Python is a **statement**, *not* an expression -- which explains the syntax-error part of your problem.

(There are other syntax errors, such as that `for x` not followed by an `in`, so Python might be diagnosing any one of them, in fact).

Since you want to assign, use a plain loop, such as:

```
for key in My_dict:
   for x in My_dict[key]['Subset']:
       if x[2] == 2: x[1] = x[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the for-loop as per Alex Martelli's answer is probably best, but if

1. you want to use list comprehensions, and
2. you don't mind that new lists are being generated and assigned, instead of the original lists being mutated

then here's an alternative solution:

```
for sub_dict in My_dict.itervalues():
    sub_dict['Subset'] = [x[:1] + x[2:3] + x[2:] if x[2] == 2 else x for x in sub_dict['Subset']]
    print sub_dict['Subset']
```

**Edit** Since you're never using the `key` value, I changed the for-loop to work directly with the sub-dictionaries returned by `itervalues()`.